# Run-time error '92': For loop not initialized

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I want to import .doc or .docx files, draw out certain elements and order them in an Excel sheet.

I initiate a macro that creates a matrix, containing the inputs from the document, that correspond to a heading in the Word file.
This results in error '92' (first for-loop -> Next). The error only occurs on some files. I assume the content/headings/structure of the document has influence as well.

```vb
'### GET TYPOGRAPHY NAMES ###'
Set colStyleNames = New Collection 'create a new instance of the collection'

With wdDoc
With .Paragraphs
    For Each para In wdDoc.Paragraphs
        '1: ERROR HANDLING'
        'since the "key field" of a collection has to be unique, this will error
        'if you are trying to add a style name which already exists
        Set oStyle = para.Style
        On Error Resume Next
        colStyleNames.Add oStyle.NameLocal, oStyle.NameLocal
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    
'2: REDIM PUBLIC ARRAY'
ReDim ListB(colStyleNames.Count) As Variant 'EXTEND Public ListB to number of Styles found'

    '3: BUILD TYPOGRAPHY RETURN STRING'
    For i = 1 To colStyleNames.Count
        ListB(i) = colStyleNames(i) 'Enter StyleNames into ListB'´
    Next
     
End With
End With
Unload UserForm2 'Stop wait pop-up'
```

Comment: Should be "Next para" & "Next i"

Comment: Is it possible that `wdDoc.Paragraphs` is empty?

Comment: Side Note: Those With Blocks are not referenced in your code. 1. You can write it in one line like: `With wdDoc.Paragraphs`. 2. None of your lines make use of the statement by referencing properties of `wdDoc.Paragraphs`.

Comment: Hello, a quick update. These answers helped me fix the issue and lean out my code, whilst helping my understanding. Thank you very much!